# Bootstrap Scrolling in Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to implement following template

http://www.bootply.com/render/96266.

Its is the working in pc but when i open in mobile it will stoped working in nokia lumia 520.
In this link scrolling is not working.

In mobile navigation bar is goes to hidden but when i click for show it, it's show but not scroll out.

this is the code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootply.com - Bootstrap Faceboot - A Facebook style template for Bootstrap</title>
        <title>undefined</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/bootstrap/img/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/bootstrap/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

        <!-- CSS code from Bootply.com editor -->

        <style type="text/css">
            /* custom template */
    html, body {
   height: 100%;
   font-family:verdana,arial,sans-serif;
   color:#555555;
}

.nav {
   font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
   font-size:13px;
}

a {
  color:#222222;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}

hr {
  border-color:#dedede;
}

.wrapper, .row {
   height: 100%;
   margin-left:0;
   margin-right:0;
}

.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after,
.column:before, .column:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.wrapper:after,
.column:after {
    clear: both;
}

.column {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    *zoom:1;
}

.column .padding {
    padding: 20px;
}

.full{
    padding-top:70px;
}

.box {
    bottom: 0; /* increase for footer use */
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color:#444444;
  /*
    background-image:url('/assets/example/bg_suburb.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
  */
}

.divider {
    margin-top:32px;
}

.navbar-blue {
    border-width:0;
    background-color:#3B5999;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:inherit;
}

.navbar-blue li > a,.navbar-toggle  {
   color:#efefef;
}

.navbar-blue .dropdown-menu li a {color:#2A4888;}
.navbar-blue .dropdown-menu li > a {padding-left:30px;}

.navbar-blue li>a:hover, .navbar-blue li>a:focus, .navbar-blue .open, .navbar-blue .open>a, .navbar-blue .open>a:hover, .navbar-blue .open>a:focus {
   background-color:#2A4888;
   color:#fff;
}

#main {
   background-color:#e9eaed;
   padding-left:0;
   padding-right:0;
}
#main .img-circle {
   margin-top:18px;
   height:70px;
   width:70px;
}

#sidebar {
    padding:0px;
    padding-top:15px;
}

#sidebar, #sidebar a, #sidebar-footer a {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:transparent;
    text-shadow:0 0 2px #000000;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#sidebar .nav li>a:hover {
    background-color:#393939;
}

.logo {
  display:block;
  padding:3px;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#3B5999;
  height:28px;
  width:28px;
  margin:9px;
  margin-right:2px;
  margin-left:15px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px;
  border-radius:2px;
}
#sidebar-footer {
  background-color:#444;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  padding:5px;
}
#footer {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

/* bootstrap overrides */

h1,h2,h3 {
   font-weight:800;
}

.navbar-toggle, .close {
    outline:0;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.btn-primary,.label-primary,.list-group-item.active, .list-group-item.active:hover, .list-group-item.active:focus  {
    background-color:#3B5999;
    color:#fffffe;
}
.btn-default {
    color:#666666;
    text-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.form-control {

}

.panel textarea, .well textarea, textarea.form-control
{
   resize: none;
}

.badge{
   color:#3B5999;
   background-color:#fff;
}
.badge:hover, .badge-inverse{
   background-color:#3B5999;
   color:#fff;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color:transparent;
}
.label-default {
  background-color:#dddddd;
}
.page-header {
  margin-top: 55px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  border-top:1px solid #eeeeee;
  font-weight:700;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

.panel-default .panel-heading {
  background-color:#f9fafb;
  color:#555555;
}

.col-sm-9.full {
    width: 100%;
}

.modal-header, .modal-footer {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    font-weight:800;
    font-size:12px;
}

.modal-footer i, .well i {
    font-size:20px;
    color:#c0c0c0;
}

.modal-body {
    padding:0px;
}

.modal-body textarea.form-control
{
   resize: none;
   border:0;
   box-shadow:0 0 0;
}

small.text-muted {
  font-family:courier,courier-new,monospace;
}

/* adjust the contents on smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

  .column .padding {
    padding: 7px;
  }

  .full{
    padding-top:20px;
  }

  .navbar-blue {
    background-color:#3B5999;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  }

}


/*
 * off canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 33%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 33%;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  #sidebar, #sidebar a, #sidebar-footer a {
    padding-left:3px;
  }
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->

    <body  >

        <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">


            <!-- sidebar -->
            <div class="column col-sm-2 col-xs-1 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">

                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="offcanvas" class="visible-xs text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav hidden-xs" id="lg-menu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#featured"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Featured</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#stories"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Stories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i> Saved</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> Refresh</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled hidden-xs" id="sidebar-footer">
                    <li>
                      <a href="http://www.bootply.com"><h3>Bootstrap</h3> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"></i> Bootply</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- tiny only nav-->
              <ul class="nav visible-xs" id="xs-menu">
                    <li><a href="#featured" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#stories" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="text-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!-- /sidebar -->

            <!-- main right col -->
            <div class="column col-sm-10 col-xs-11" id="main">

                <!-- top nav -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-blue navbar-static-top">  
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand logo">b</a>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="max-width:360px;">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                          <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#postModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Post</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#"><span class="badge">badge</span></a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                          <li><a href="">More</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <!-- /top nav -->

                <div class="padding">
                    <div class="full col-sm-9">

                        <!-- content -->                      
                        <div class="row">

                         <!-- main col left --> 
                         <div class="col-sm-5">

                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-thumbnail"><img src="/assets/example/bg_5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                  <p class="lead">Urbanization</p>
                                  <p>45 Followers, 13 Posts</p>

                                  <p>
                                    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uFp_tsTJboUY7kue5XAsGA=s28" width="28px" height="28px">
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>


                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>Bootstrap Examples</h4></div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="list-group">
                                      <a href="http://bootply.com/tagged/modal" class="list-group-item">Modal / Dialog</a>
                                      <a href="http://bootply.com/tagged/datetime" class="list-group-item">Datetime Examples</a>
                                      <a href="http://bootply.com/tagged/datatable" class="list-group-item">Data Grids</a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="well"> 
                                   <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    <h4>What's New</h4>
                                     <div class="form-group" style="padding:14px;">
                                      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Update your status"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button">Post</button><ul class="list-inline"><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></a></li></ul>
                                  </form>
                              </div>

                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                 <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>More Templates</h4></div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle pull-right"> <a href="#">Free @Bootply</a>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    There a load of new free Bootstrap 3 ready templates at Bootply. All of these templates are free and don't require extensive customization to the Bootstrap baseline.
                                    <hr>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled"><li><a href="http://www.bootply.com/templates">Dashboard</a></li><li><a href="http://www.bootply.com/templates">Darkside</a></li><li><a href="http://www.bootply.com/templates">Greenfield</a></li></ul>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading"><h4>What Is Bootstrap?</h4></div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    Bootstrap is front end frameworkto build custom web applications that are fast, responsive &amp; intuitive. It consist of CSS and HTML for typography, forms, buttons, tables, grids, and navigation along with custom-built jQuery plug-ins and support for responsive layouts. With dozens of reusable components for navigation, pagination, labels, alerts etc..                          </div>
                              </div>



                          </div>

                          <!-- main col right -->
                          <div class="col-sm-7">

                                <div class="well"> 
                                   <form class="form">
                                    <h4>Sign-up</h4>
                                    <div class="input-group text-center">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                                      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">OK</button></span>
                                    </div>
                                  </form>
                                </div>

                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                 <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>Bootply Editor &amp; Code Library</h4></div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p><img src="//placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle pull-right"> <a href="#">The Bootstrap Playground</a></p>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <hr>
                                    Design, build, test, and prototype using Bootstrap in real-time from your Web browser. Bootply combines the power of hand-coded HTML, CSS and JavaScript with the benefits of responsive design using Bootstrap. Find and showcase Bootstrap-ready snippets in the 100% free Bootply.com code repository.
                                  </div>
                               </div>

                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                 <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>Stackoverflow</h4></div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <img src="//placehold.it/150x150" class="img-circle pull-right"> <a href="#">Keyword: Bootstrap</a>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <hr>

                                    <p>If you're looking for help with Bootstrap code, the <code>twitter-bootstrap</code> tag at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap">Stackoverflow</a> is a good place to find answers.</p>

                                    <hr>
                                    <form>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                                      <button class="btn btn-default">+1</button><button class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></i></button>
                                      </div>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment..">
                                    </div>
                                    </form>

                                  </div>
                               </div>

                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                 <div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" class="pull-right">View all</a> <h4>Portlet Heading</h4></div>
                                  <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Modals</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Sliders / Carousel</li>
                                    <li class="list-group-item">Thumbnails</li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                               </div>

                               <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-thumbnail"><img src="/assets/example/bg_4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                  <p class="lead">Social Good</p>
                                  <p>1,200 Followers, 83 Posts</p>

                                  <p>
                                    <img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-5cTTMHjjnzs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAFk/vgza68M4p2s/s28-c-k-no/photo.jpg" width="28px" height="28px">
                                    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-6aFMDiaLg5M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABdM/XjnG8z60Ug0/s28-c-k-no/photo.jpg" width="28px" height="28px">
                                    <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-9Yw2jNffJlE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/u3WcFXvK-g8/s28-c-k-no/photo.jpg" width="28px" height="28px">
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                          </div>
                       </div><!--/row-->

                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#">Twitter</a> <small class="text-muted">|</small> <a href="#">Facebook</a> <small class="text-muted">|</small> <a href="#">Google+</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="footer">    
                          <div class="col-sm-6">

                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <p>
                            <a href="#" class="pull-right">©Copyright 2013</a>
                            </p>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      <hr>

                      <h4 class="text-center">
                      <a href="http://bootply.com/96266" target="ext">Download this Template @Bootply</a>
                      </h4>

                      <hr>


                    </div><!-- /col-9 -->
                </div><!-- /padding -->
            </div>
            <!-- /main -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--post modal-->
<div id="postModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            Update Status
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control input-lg" autofocus="" placeholder="What do you want to share?"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Post</button>
            <ul class="pull-left list-inline"><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i></a></li><li><a href=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></a></li></ul>
          </div>    
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

        <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>







        <!-- JavaScript jQuery code from Bootply.com editor  -->

        <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            /* off-canvas sidebar toggle */

$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible-xs text-center');
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('#lg-menu').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
    $('#xs-menu').toggleClass('visible-xs').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    $('#btnShow').toggle();
});

        });

        </script>

        <script>
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          ga('create', 'UA-40413119-1', 'bootply.com');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <!-- Quantcast Tag -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _qevents = _qevents || [];

        (function() {
        var elem = document.createElement('script');
        elem.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://secure" : "http://edge") + ".quantserve.com/quant.js";
        elem.async = true;
        elem.type = "text/javascript";
        var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, scpt);
        })();

        _qevents.push({
        qacct:"p-0cXb7ATGU9nz5"
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide question with less code, txanks

Comment: Can you put the code you are using into a JSfiddle? Might make it easier to get to the bottom of this, and more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is to compare the code you've placed here with the Bootply code you referenced. I notice when I reverse the class names which Bootply is using, using the console/web inspector from inside a browser, and put them in the opposite order like YOU have: `class="collapse navbar-collapse"` the Bootply toggle button stops working entirely.

So I'm wondering if you've tried putting those class names in proper order as `class="navbar-collapse collapse"` instead? That might be one place to start. Without being able to see your code in a working demo it's kind of hard to say. Tried to dump it into a fiddle but it didn't work well. Here's the link if you want to finish arranging it properly for a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/t2VYu/